# filter result from array than display key & results for each index in php

Tags: php, arrays

I have an data array where i am getting results as `var_dump($get_data);`

```
array(45) {
    ["sitelock"] => array(4) {
        [181] => array(2) {
            ["plan_name"] => string(10) "Enterprise" 
            ["plan_status"] => string(6) "Active"
        } 
        [180] => array(2) {
            ["plan_name"] => string(7) "Premium" 
            ["plan_status"] => string(6) "Active"
        } 
        [179] => array(2) {
            ["plan_name"] => string(12) "Professional" 
            ["plan_status"] => string(6) "Active"
        } 
        [178] => array(2) {
            ["plan_name"] => string(5) "Basic" 
            ["plan_status"] => string(6) "Active"
        }
    } 
    ["codeguard"] => array(4) {
        [230] => array(2) {
            ["plan_name"] => string(12) "Professional" 
            ["plan_status"] => string(6) "Active"
        } 
        [229] => array(2) {
            ["plan_name"] => string(5) "Basic" 
            ["plan_status"] => string(6) "Active"
        } 
        [232] => array(2) {
            ["plan_name"] => string(10) "Enterprise" 
            ["plan_status"] => string(6) "Active"
        } 
        [231] => array(2) {
            ["plan_name"] => string(7) "Premium" 
            ["plan_status"] => string(6) "Active"
        }
    }
}
```

Step 1 = I would like to filter `sitelock` from an array than i want to display it's key value `181,180,179,178` as pid in list and `["plan_name"]` values are respectively as Enterprise, Premium, Professional, Basic

Here is expected result example:

```
pid  Plan Name
181  Enterprise
180  Premium
179  Professional
181  Enterprise
181  Basic
```

So far I am trying something like this

```
$get_data = json_decode($data,true);
//var_dump( $get_data);
$productkey = "sitelock";
foreach($get_data as $key => $value) {
    if($key == $productkey) {
        // table code goes here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to loop through key `sitelock` of `$get_data` and in loop create new array contain custom data you want.

```
$arr = [];
foreach($get_data['sitelock'] as $key => $value){
    $arr[$key] = $value['plan_name'];
}
```

Check result in [demo](https://3v4l.org/U5cpY)